# Operations in a "RESTful" API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, api-design

I have slideshows.  Each slideshow consists of slide.

The following will return a list of ordered slides in a slideshow:

**`GET api/slideshows/123/slides`**:

```
{
    {
        slideId : "22",
        name : "My slide"
    },
    {
        slideId : "25",
        name : "My second slide"
    },
    {
        slideId : "26",
        name : "Another slide"
    }
}
```

I want to perform the following operation, for example:

*Move slide 26 to the position after slide 22*

**What is a good way to expose such a request?**

Either we can PUT the whole slides collection in a different order, but this will replace all the slide data if there happen to be more changes. Plus it could be a lot of data to transfer.

```
PUT api/slideshows/123/slides
```

Another option is to supply a `moveAfter` "operation":

```
POST api/slideshows/123/slides/26?action=moveAfter
body: 
{
    referenceId : "22"
}
```

I understand that this isn't entirely RESTful, but what other practical solutions exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this: `PUT api/slideshows/123/slides/26/position 22`.

Btw. it is interesting. You can do it 2 ways:

- every slide has a unique id, which does not depend on the order
- the id is the same as the order index (or position) - in this case you have to update the whole collection after every move, because the server maintains the resource state and not the client, so it will be much slower.

Comment: Nesting URIs so deeply can really be problematic. It's better to go with a flat structure and represent resource associations via content in the resources, rather than in their URIs.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following design.

- The key point here is that the slides for a slideshow are just an array of URIs pointing to the constituent slide resources.  To reorder, add, or remove slides from a slideshow, you PATCH the slideshow resource with the new slides array.
- Creating a slide is done independent of the slideshow that references it. Associations between slideshows and slides can only be changed by doing a PATCH on the slideshow resource.
- Resource URIs do not nest deeply.  That is a poor design choice that can come back to bite you later.

I illustrate it with a series of request-response pairs.

```
GET /slideshows/17
200 OK
{
    "slideshow_id": 17,
    "slides": [
        "/slides/15",
        "/slides/42",
        "/slides/76",
        "/slides/31"
    ]
}

POST /slides
{
    "content": "..."
}
201 Created
Location: /slides/93

GET /slides/93
200 OK
{
    "slide_id": 93,
    "slideshow_association": null,
    "content": "..."
}

PATCH /slideshows/17
{
    "slides": [
        "/slides/15",
        "/slides/31"
        "/slides/42",
        "/slides/76",
        "/slides/93"
    ] 
}
204 No Content

GET /slides/93
200 OK
{
    "slide_id": 93,
    "slideshow_association": {
        "slideshow": "/slideshows/17",
        "index": 4,
        "previous_slide": "/slides/76",
        "next_slide": null
    },
    "content": "..."
}
```